# Positioning error IE with fancybox

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, fancybox

hello guys im having problems with Internet Explorer positioning (as usual...) the problem is when I click on the thumbnail it has to pop up a slideshow in the center/ middle of the page 
firefox/chrome works perfectly but Internet Explorer refuses to work like that and it puts the slideshow on the bottom of the page.

Here is the website: 217.120.183.184/cdweb/Portfolio/

If you need any further information feel free to ask me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The headers aren't correctly set :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: bro this helped me so much :) i totally forgot about that i even double checked my code but overlooked that thank you so much, Greetings, Darren Brown

Answer (score 0):

Try to add correct DOCTYPE.
It's the first rule on the official site http://fancybox.net/howto